# Show Backbutton in Toolbar using styles

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar

I would like to pass toolbar theme to my other library's class in AndroidManifest. I have declared the theme in styles.xml as follows:

```
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/back</item>
        <item name="title">@string/app_name</item>
        <item name="subtitle">@string/app_version</item>
    </style>
```

Whereas, the back button is not visible while displaying that library's class. So is there a way to `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` to true in `styles.xml` itself??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use, `navigationIcon` option to show icon using `styles.xml`.

If you're targetting API 21+,

```
<item name="android:navigationIcon">@drawable/back</item>
```

Otherwise,

```
<item name="navigationIcon">@drawable/back</item>
```

So, my theme should be,

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="title">@string/app_name</item>
        <item name="subtitle">@string/app_version</item>
        <item name="navigationIcon">@drawable/back</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/backbutton"//imp code
    app:title="Check Out"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_checkout_main">
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

in xml declare the app:navigationicon and in java file use

```
 toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(v -> {
        //on backbutton pressed code//
    });
```

Comment: Hi @raj, I have to do that in styles.xml, since I have to set the theme to library's class in Manifest, which doesn't have any instance of toolbar for customization.